# Emacs 24 error on startup

Tags: emacs, elisp, traceback

I have been using emacs snapshot for a while now but recently it has been crashing a lot. So I switched to Emacs 24. But once I installed it and started it up it started showing error and wouldn't load anything in my init.el

when I ran it in debug mode, I got this.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function package--description-file)
(package--description-file pkg-dir)                                            
(expand-file-name (package--description-file pkg-dir) pkg-dir)
```

The full trace is [here](http://pastebin.com/gGzdaV8D).

Any help in fixing this or understanding the trackback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll hazard a guess that you have some byte-compiled .elc files from your usage of the snapshot version, which are getting called. Or even .el files, I guess.

My presumption is that `package--description-file` function exists in the snapshot version, as it's not in the stable Emacs 24.3 release (which is why you're getting the error), and thus somehow you're evaluating code from the snapshot release.

Comment: I agree with @phils. And yes, `package--description-file` exists in Emacs 24 dev snapshots (for 24.4), and it does not exist in 24.3. Ensure that the snapshot directories for Lisp files are not in your `load-path`.

Comment: I had to remove all the elc and all the installed packages to get back everything running. Not sure which exact part caused the problem but it was a result of incompatibility between snapshot and emacs 24.